# Inequality with $a_1,a_2, \cdots , a_n$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

> Let $n \geqslant 2$ be an integer and let $1<a_1 \le a_2 \le \dots \le a_n$ be $n$ real numbers such that $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n=2n$. Prove that$$a_1a_2\dots a_{n-1}+a_1a_2\dots a_{n-2}+\dots+a_1a_2+a_1+2 \leqslant a_1a_2\dots a_n.$$

---

I feel something is very wrong with my solution, but I can't figure it out. We will proceed with induction. We shall show the base case of $2$ [which I'm not including as it is not of any concern]. Assume the statement is true for $n$, hence we need to show it's true for $n+1$, that is $$2+a_1+a_1 a_2+...+a_1 a_2...a_n \leq a_1 a_2 ...a_n a_{n+1}$$ Note that the LHS is less than or equal to $2a_1 a_2 ... a_n$ using induction hypothesis [ that is $a_1a_2\dots a_{n-1}+a_1a_2\dots a_{n-2}+\dots+a_1a_2+a_1+2 \leqslant a_1a_2\dots a_n$]. Now if we can show $$2a_1 a_2 ... a_n \leq a_1 a_2 ...a_n a_{n+1}$$ Which is equivalent to showing $$2 \leq a_{n+1}$$ Now notice, $$a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n+ a_{n+1}=2n+2$$ and $$a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n=2n$$ From these two equation, we can get $a_{n+1}=2$. So $2 \leq a_{n+1}$ is true and hence we are done. Where is this proof wrong?

Comment: See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1989009 I hope it will help.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I have gone through that thread, and all the (inductive) solutions there are different and much complex than mine. That's why I suspect that my solution is wrong, but still I can't pinpoint where it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the induction hypothesis clearly would mean: given any sequence $a_1,...,a_n$
Such that:

$1 < a_1 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$

$a_1+...+a_n = 2n$

Then
$2+a_1+\ldots+a_{n-1} \ldots a_1 \leq a_n\ldots a_1$

Now if you take a sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1}$ satisfying the two conditions for $n+1$, then you don't necessarily have that $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ satisfies the conditions for $n$.
Specifically you don't control
$a_1+...+a_n$

The structure of a proof by induction is, you have a statement $P(n)$, in this case $P(n)$ is that all increasing n-tuples of sum $2n$ of integers strictly greater than 1 satisfy the given inequality.
You prove the base case, and that for all n bigger than 2, you suppose that $P(n)$ is true and you show $P(n+1)$.

So if you take any increasing (n+1)-tuple of sum $2n+2$ of integers strictly greater than 1, you have no idea what the first n values have as sum, since that is just the hypothesis (not the conclusion) of the induction statement...

Hence you can't use the induction hypothesis on them directly as you did.

Comment: "then you don't necessarily have that $a_1,…,a_n$
 satisfies the conditions for n" why is that the case? How does $a_1,...,a_n$ lose their property one we extend it to $n+1$ terms?

Comment: Why would $a_1+\ldots+a_{n+1}=2n+2$ imply that $a_1+\ldots+a_n=2n$ ?

Comment: I hope my edit clarifies things